# How can I cross-compile Scala versions that support different core library APIs?

Tags: scala

I'm building a library I want to support Scala 2.12 and 2.13 targets.  There are a few differences between these versions that are just incompatible, meaning I need different code for a few areas between the 2 versions.

For example 2.12.x Builder (abstract class) requires you to implement a method '+='.  In 2.13.x '+=' is now final and you need to implement method 'addOne'.  Argh.  A few things like that.

What's the best way (using sbt) to organize my build to accommodate the differences, since Scala doesn't have conditional compilation?

Comment: You can take a look at the source code of [**Cats**](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) or other projects that do the same. They have special folders for code that are version dependent. Then configure **SBT** to only include those folder when compiling with the appropriate **Scala** version.

Comment: SBT already handles source folders like `src/main/scala-2.12` or `src/main/scala-2.13` exactly as one would expect and as you seem to desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Luis Miguel and Sascha's answers are correct.  Cats does have a good example and SBT has this ability.  Couldn't find it in the docs, but it's explained here: https://github.com/twitter/util/issues/219