# Using subrepo for Chisel project errs

Tags: sbt, chisel

I am trying to use the AsyncQueue subrepo (https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue) in my own project, much as the ClockDividerDemo in Chisel Multiclock Demos (https://github.com/edwardcwang/chisel-multiclock-demo/).
However, sbt errs:

```
[error] ... .scala:9:8: not found: object freechips
[error] import freechips.asyncqueue.{AsyncQueue, AsyncQueueParams}
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
```

To be specific, I added these lines to the tail of my build.sbt:

```
lazy val asyncqueue = (project in file("asyncqueue-lite"))
lazy val myself = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(asyncqueue)
```

And this line to my own Scala file:

```
import freechips.asyncqueue.{AsyncQueue, AsyncQueueParams}
```

EDIT:

Complete build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0"

val chiselVersion = "3.6.0"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "asyncqueue-chisel",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % chiselVersion,
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "0.6.0" % "test"
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:reflectiveCalls",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature",
      "-Xcheckinit"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" % "chisel3-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full
    )
  )

lazy val asyncqueue = (project in file("asyncqueue-lite"))
lazy val myself = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(asyncqueue)
```

Comment: With those two lines in your `build.sbt` is not enough. You need to add the required libraries to `libraryDependencies`. If you already did that, please edit your post an show what you got. Try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @GastónSchabas Thanks - I added the complete build.sbt above. Did experiment with libraryDependencies, but was not successfull so far.

Comment: @GastónSchabas One of the experiments was to add the line `"edu.berkeley.cs" %% "asyncqueue-lite" % "2.0.0"` to libraryDependencies, but didnt seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any release published in any artifactory for [asyncqueue](https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue). To make your project depends on that one, [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) lets you [use projects directly from github](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse/) when they are not packed.

The steps to solve the issue are:

1. Replace how `asyncqueue` project is defined

```scala
// instead of
lazy val asyncqueue = (project in file("asyncqueue-lite"))
// use
lazy val asyncqueue = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue.git"))
```

2. Add `asyncqueue` as a dependency

```scala
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(asyncqueue) // <- this is how you make your project depends on another one
  .settings(
    name := "asyncqueue-chisel",
    // ...
  )
```

3. downgrade `scala` to `2.12.17`

   - [asyncqueue](https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue) depends on [scala 2.12](https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue/blob/aa1f640aba7ac80060d9ef6571eac9a93128ee44/build.sbt#L31). You can fork the project and try to make build a released compatible with `scala 2.13`. Here you have a question about [How a core library can be cross-compiled for different scala versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385751/how-can-i-cross-compile-scala-versions-that-support-different-core-library-apis)
   - [chisel3-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.berkeley.cs/chisel3-plugin) doesn't have a release for `scala 2.12.18` which is the [latest scala 2.12.x released on June 7, 2023](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html)

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
```

4. downgrade `chisel3` to `3.5.5`. Using `3.5.6` or `3.6.0` will cause some conflict version. The following error message will be showed

```scala
[error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error]
[error]     * edu.berkeley.cs:chisel3_2.12:3.5.6 (pvp) is selected over {3.1.+, 3.1.8}
[error]         +- asyncqueue-chisel:asyncqueue-chisel_2.12:0.1.0     (depends on 3.5.6)
[error]         +- edu.berkeley.cs:chisel-iotesters_2.12:1.2.10       (depends on 3.1.8)
[error]         +- asyncqueue-lite:asyncqueue-lite_2.12:1.0.0         (depends on 3.1.+)
```

This is how you can set the correct `chisel3` version

```scala
val chiselVersion = "3.5.5"
```

---

Now, your `build.sbt` should look like

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0"

val chiselVersion = "3.5.5"

lazy val UcbBarAsyncQueue = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue.git"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(UcbBarAsyncQueue)
  .settings(
    name := "asyncqueue-chisel",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % chiselVersion,
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "0.6.0" % "test"
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:reflectiveCalls",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature",
      "-Xcheckinit"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" % "chisel3-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full
    )
  )
```

and the line

```scala
import freechips.asyncqueue.{AsyncQueue, AsyncQueueParams}
```

should compile without errors

Comment: Great response, thanks! My bad though, I failed to update my post, as I tried this PR:
https://github.com/ucb-bar/asyncqueue/pull/4/commits/417c76fc8992e1efe49c8c9ee3d7f3d2819e9efc#diff-386cc5c76d41dc3a39b8b77aca311619978eb5b18af7d1af01041cbb14bc0a4a
There are a number of updates in this PR. But even so, I still get an error:
`[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading edu.berkeley.cs:asyncqueue-lite_2.13:1.0.0`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do know. Your `build.sbt` have a project with the name `asyncqueue-chisel` and that PR is for a project named `asyncqueue-lite`. If my answer was enough to solve the problem of the original question and now you have a new issue, please create a new post adding all the debugging details you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I need the following build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0"

val chiselVersion = "3.6.0"

lazy val asyncqueue = (project in file("asyncqueue"))
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .dependsOn(asyncqueue)
  .settings(
    name := "asyncqueue-chisel",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % chiselVersion,
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "0.6.0" % "test"
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:reflectiveCalls",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature",
      "-Xcheckinit"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" % "chisel3-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full
    )
  )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).